Can't bypass powershell execution policy launching a remote .ps1 script with NT AUTHORITY\System
Since I started debugging this 2 days ago, I just told myself I should ask for some help.
(This used to work like a month ago (and still works on my lab), but for some reason I ignore don't work now on prod-env.)
I created a scheduled task inside a GPO to launch a .ps1 script that is on an internal server, with NT AUTHORY\System user.
As the task didn't seem to apply, I tried to launch the script by hand and saw that the PowerShell ExecutionPolicy isn't bypassed even though I used "-ExecutionPolicy Bypassed" in my command.
C:>whoami
nt authority\system

C:>powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \\server\scripts\myscript.ps1

Security Warning 
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the Internet 
can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer. Do 
you want to run \\server\scripts\myscript.ps1? [D] Do not run [R] Run 
once [S] Suspend [?] Help (default is "D"):

If I accept the execution of the script, it works and what the task must achieve is perfectly done.
I tried to execute the same script located on my laptop and the ExecutionPolicy is bypassed.
I also tried to execute it as a standard user, remotly and localy, and ExecutionPolicy is bypassed too (even though the user doesn't have rights to execute the script).
Here's the ExecutionPolicy for each user, but I don't know if it matters since I ask to bypass it :
Standard User :
    Scope ExecutionPolicy
    ----- ---------------
 MachinePolicy    Unrestricted
    UserPolicy       Undefined
       Process       Undefined
   CurrentUser       Undefined
  LocalMachine       Undefined

NT AUTHORITY\System :
    Scope ExecutionPolicy
    ----- ---------------
 MachinePolicy    Unrestricted
    UserPolicy    Unrestricted
       Process       Undefined
   CurrentUser       Undefined
  LocalMachine       Undefined

